# Minimalistic git pull tool

Tags: git, git-pull

I have a project that is hosted on remote server which development is done with git and when a time for release comes, updates should be uploaded to the server from the repository, to do this I need to either download a tarball, or install full git distribution to the server, but neither of this is really convenient. I have no need for git on the server, I do no development there, I make no changes at all, repository files are nothing but trash, all I need is `pull`.

So, is there a tool that can read commit history of the repo, compare current version with latest remote, download and install all the necessary patches and nothing more?

Comment: Why can't you just install git on the server? Should take about 30 seconds, depending on your package manager.

Comment: Because I [don't really need it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor) there, if there's a tool that does exactly what I need, I'd rather use it.

Answer (score 2):

Installing git is the best option. You may think you don't need it, but it's good for a number of reasons to have the whole system:

- You can do the task you've described with a single line of code
- You can see exactly what version of the software you are checked out at using git log
- You can switch back and forth between branches of your code instantly, without having to fiddle about re-downloading stuff or moving files from place to place
- You can turn on debugging/error logging variables in your production code if there is a bug you cannot reproduce locally, then revert to production code with a single command by switching branches
- If you do make any changes on the server, you can instantly see with git diff or git status, so you can't turn on debugging and then forget where/whether you did so

You say you don't need the whole repo history, but even for a large project, are you really that short of space? Storage is very cheap.

I now use git routinely on the servers even though I never intend to do any work there (the server even has no permissions to push to the repo) because it saves so much time and hassle for exactly the situation you describe.

Edit: Re your Occam's Razor comment - I've seen people take the same 'not strictly necessary' approach to regular off-site backups. It didn't end well ;)

Comment: And it's not like git is some huge bloated software package with a 300 MB installer, either. Anything with a subset of git's functionality isn't going to manage to be much more lightweight than git itself.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install git, but if you have a reason to can't do this, you can use [ViewGit](http://viewgit.fealdia.org/). You can read commit history, compare, and download files.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem you're trying to solve is to just get the latest version of some files up to a server (overwriting any changes there), have you considered just using `rsync`?